# A local repository to update games?

Tags: git, svn, repository

I have a computer cafe. Updating and maintaining files (particularly games) has been a hassle for me and my employees. In addition, I am not willing to pay for something like G-Cafe Management Program. I am familiar with programming languages like C, PHP, JAVA, but I am neither aware of what logic and algorithm I would use for my objective nor familiar with networking

My friend suggested I use a local repository, so I researched topics regarding the same matter. But it turns out that I have a question that was not answered by discussions I've read.

This is how I view how my update was going to work:

I plan on updating games through this flow: [(Internet -> Server) -> (Server -> Client]. If there are game updates, the local server will download it through the internet; then, the client will copy or download these files from the local server.

Seeing that games have autoupdaters, I plan on placing all of the games inside the repository (in the server) and the client stations will connect to that repository. But then again, SVN works with revisions, am I right?

Are there any suggestions or ideas whether how will I be able to update client games through SVN / Git (of course from the server)? Or if there are any other ways?

I was playing too dumb.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that comes to mind is the use of disk images.

Assuming your machines are all exactly the same, you could easily keep one in the back that is a master image with all games installed and updated (nightly, weekly, monthly, up to you) and then push the image on a regular basis (probably weekly, on days you are closed) to all the client machines.

Comment: (I'm sorry if this is a stupid question) Manually push the image or through the use of some software?

Comment: I've been hearing updating through MD5 Hash.. is a possible method, too?

Comment: @KierBorromeo It depends on the disk image software in use. Some can be pushed through a network, others have to be pushed manually via sneaker-net and a flash drive. It's my understanding that MD5 Hashing is just a way to verify the integrity of a file, it wouldn't help much in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Version Control Systems work with revisions, yes, that counts for either SVN and git. In case of new program versions it naturally makes sense to put them into revisions, as they are usually only a snapshot of XYZ in a certain point in time. XYZ being whatever want it to be, binary programs, images, files, etc.

But to make it really part of a revision you would also need to commit the newly fetched changes. That in the end makes a new revision of your (let's say) games tree.

Those revisions then can be fetched from the client computers. That can happen either by scripts that automatically check the server every couple of minutes (cronjobs?) for changes or manually.

The benefit of that workflow is quite obvious, in case your new versions are not what you want (e.g. later you notice they are broken) you can roll back your changes to the last known working revision.

Comment: So you're proposing to use SCM for multi-gigabyte binary files distribution?

Comment: The question was based on a SCM, so this answer is based on that as well

Comment: have you ever tried to create and checkout an svn/git repository with say 20 Gb of binary data? (which will easily grow to 100 after couple game refreshes). SCMs are mostly designed to keep track of *textual changes*, not for distribution

Comment: That is simply wrong. I have seen a lot of repositories which have binary data, yes (thinking of e.g. images only, unlikely textual). Of course they grow in size, and one SCM system more than the other. That doesn't make it wrong per se. It depends on the available resources and of course the environment, which was not stated in the original question.

Comment: well, just try to checkout 20Gb binaries one day. And keep in mind that it will be *at least* doubled on the client machine. Also keep in mind that the size will *constantly grow* on server. Apart of that, I agree that you can nail the nail with microscope, point taken.

Comment: "It depends on the available resources and of course the environment, which was not stated in the original question" --- could you provide an example of environment when it will be the only/the best solution? (assuming you know what `rsync` or any similar tool is for)

Comment: checking out 20gb is probably not a lot of fun, agreed. But i wonder if each game is that big. And how much of the games files really is changed (it is unlikely one big 20gb binary blob unless it has changed a lot recently). But even if it is, you get the same effect with images then, one for each new version is even worse than a new revision in e.g. svn. Anyway, after some time you have - let's say - 5 updated games on the local server, and let's even say they are 20gb in total, considering it is a local server it is not as bad as fetching the games directly from the internet.

Comment: Again, read the original question, it was only asked about SCM's. Of course does rsync make a lot sense, but how do you handle different versions then? Forget about them, it will work anyway?

Comment: And additionally, it was not even stated, about what environment we are talking here

Comment: "Again, read the original question, it was only asked about SCM's" -- that's because of lack of knowledge. OP needs a tool to **distribute** binaries, not to track their changes. "but how do you handle different versions then" --- using rsync. You want the older version - you install it on a central server and deploy it to the clients.

Comment: It is probably nice to anticipate somebody's knowledge without any further feedback...

Comment: The important thing you're missing - is that the revision is a state of the **whole** repository tree. So rolling back a game A while having the games B and C of the latest version isn't a trivial task

Comment: "without any further feedback" --- I've left a useful answer in the question comments :-) It's fine to now know something, I don't see why you think it's bad.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35807/discussion-between-zerkms-and-neverendingo)